# Performance Issue Caching Images UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

I am parsing an RSS feed, and then caching the images from the rss feed and then displaying them in the cell's imageview. However the method I am using, slows down the rss feed's parse time, and slows down the TableView's scroll time. Please could you tell me how I could speed up this process. One of the image links is: http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/009/Video/95/5d/25/mzl.gnygbsji.71x53-75.jpg, and one of the rss feeds I am trying to parse is: http://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topmovies/limit=50/xml. Here is the code I am using to cache the images:

`- (UIImage )getCachedImage: (NSString)url
{`

```
UIImage* theImage = [imageCache objectForKey:url];

if ((nil != theImage) && [theImage isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
    return theImage;
}
else {
    theImage = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]]];
    [imageCache setObject:theImage forKey:url];
    return theImage;
     } 
}
```

And the code I am using to get the images is:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
 int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
 int wierd = storyIndex *6;
 cell.textLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"songtitle"];
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"artist"];

 if ([imageLinks count] != 0) {
  cell.imageView.image = [self getCachedImage:[imageLinks objectAtIndex:wierd]];
 }
    return cell;
 }
```

As you can probably see, I am using an NSMutableArray called imageLinks, to store the imageLinks. However I am getting three image links from the rss feed, which means if I try to get the cached image: [imageLink objectAtIndex:storyIndex], the images are in the wrong places, but if I get the cached image: [imageLink objectAtIndex:wierd], it seems to work perfectly. So if you can see a fix to that, it would be great.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `dataWithContentsOfURL` which is a blocking API. This means that it is performed on the main thread along with your UI and will block your UI until it completes. This is bad.

You should look into the `NSURLConnection` class and it's delegate protocol, `NSURLConnectionDelegate` to do data downloads asynchronously without manually spawning and managing new threads.